# Responsive full background Image

Tags: css, media-queries, layout-responsivo, background-image

I'm having some issues with my background image.
 I have a full background image in my website, and I want a responsive website, but when I try to see it on my phone, the image height is not correct.

what resolutions should I have in the background image to fit all devices? I want to have a background image that occupies the entire screen, even at diferent heights.

(I already have media queries, but i don't know the resolutions I need)

(I think I have too many resolutions and i don't need all)

```css
body {
background-image: url("../imagens/Background/BG-1920-1080-new.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}


/* aqui troco a imagem pra cada resolução na ordem do maior pro menor */

@media screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
  body { width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
background-image: url("../imagens/Background/BG-1920-1080-new.jpg");
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
  body {
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
background-image: url("../imagens/Background/BG-1280-720.jpg");
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  body {
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
background-image: url("../imagens/Background/BG-1024-1366-new.jpg");
  }
}

@media screen
and (max-width: 1024px) and (max-height: 570px)
   {
  body {
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
background-image: url("../imagens/Background/BG-1024-7570-new.jpg");
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px), screen and (max-height: 570px) {
  body {
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
background-image: url("../imagens/Background/BG-768-570.jpg");
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
background-image: url( "../imagens/Background/BG-768-1024-new.jpg");
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
background-image: url("../imagens/Background/BG-480-320.jpg");
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 411px) {
  body { width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
background-image: url("../imagens/Background/BG-411-823-new.jpg");
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 414px){
  body { width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
background-image: url("../imagens/Background/BG-414-736-new.jpg");
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  body { width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
background-image: url("../imagens/Background/BG-425-570-new.jpg");
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px), screen and (max-height: 570px) {
  body { width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
background-image: url("../imagens/Background/BG-375-570-new.jpg");
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  body { width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
background-image: url("../imagens/Background/BG-375-667-new.jpg");
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px){
  body { width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
background-image: url("../imagens/Background/BG-375-812-new.jpg");
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  body { width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
background-image: url("../imagens/Background/BG-360-640-new.jpg");
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  body { width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
background-image: url("../imagens/Background/BG-320-480-new.jpg");
  }
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Comment: Seus `@media` estão bem confusos, pq tantos?? Outra coisa, vc tem dois `@media` iguais! http://prntscr.com/q2rytk acho que vc deveria para um pouco e tratar as imagens para ter um range maior e vc poder usar menos `@media`, da forma que está não esta legal...

Comment: Como sei quantos preciso visto que quero que dê para ver em todos os dispositivos?